# Derivative under integral for a survival function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am trying to read a textbook about survival functions. In one part, I did not understand a derivative used in the textbook. The author uses an integration by parts and gives the following derivatives

$X=\int_{0}^{T}f\left(s\right)ds$

$dX=f\left(T\right)$

and

$Y=\int_{0}^{T}U(c\left(t\right))e^{-\rho t}dt$

$dY=U(c\left(T\right))e^{-\rho T}$

where $f(s)$ is a probability density function but it is a detail. What is the logic behind these derivatives ? Is there any rule to explain it ?

Comment: Hint: use the FTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$dX = dX(T) = \frac{d}{dT}X(T)=  \frac{d}{dT}\int_0^T f(x)dx = f(T)\times1 - f(0) \times0=f(T)$$